# Invoke Castle Interceptor on Component Instance

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

Is there any easy way of getting a method on my IInterceptor to get called as soon as any instance for the relevant component is resolved? Sort of like IOnBehalfAware, but so that it gets called with the actual component instance, not the ComponentModel.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do and why?

Comment: I have some attributes on members (properties) of my intercepted component. I want my interceptor to reflect over my component and apply some logic as soon as it's resolved, then store the results. I can't use a regular OnCreate delegate, because the same IInterceptor instance needs that data later when it intercepts method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing something like this...define an interface that my `IInterceptor`(s) implement:

```
public interface IInstanceAware
{
   void Execute(object instance); 
}
```

Then when registering component(s), do

```
registration.OnCreate((kernel, instance) => 
{
   var accessor = instance as IProxyTargetAccessor;
   foreach(var instanceAware in accessor.GetInterceptors().OfType<IInstanceAware>())
   { 
       accessor.Execute(instance);
   }
};
```